# Query in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e991/1

But I have a problem! The output of my query is:

```
DATE                        SLOT    sum(SUCCESSFUL) SUCCESSFUL      PERCENTAGE  OTA_NAME     USERS_SI
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 2       120             120             41.6667     campana 2      50
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       200             200             25          campana 2      50
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       150             150             53.3333     campana 3      80
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 2       100             100             20          campana 1      20
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 3       440             440             4.5455      campana 1      20
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       700             700             2.8571      campana 1      20
```

And I need a sum of successful with the same date and campaign, for example, I have in July 1 with campaign 1 three rows, then I need sum the successful of the three rows, and with campaign 2 two rows, then I need sum the successful of the two rows, and with campaign 3 one rows, then I need sum the successful of the one row that is the same.
And finally the percentage is the division between sum(SUCCESSFUL) and USERS_SI

The output that I need is:

```
DATE                        SLOT    sum(SUCCESSFUL) SUCCESSFUL  PERCENTAGE  OTA_NAME     USERS_SI
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 2       320             120             41.6667     campana 2      50
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       320             200             25          campana 2      50
July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       150             150             53.3333     campana 3      80
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 2       1240            100             20          campana 1      20
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 3       1240            440             4.5455      campana 1      20
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 1       1240            700             2.8571      campana 1      20


Can you help me?
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is something normally done with window functions. Unfortunately MySQL has no support for those so I would recommend doing this in code instead.

Answer (score 1):

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e991/13)

```
SELECT other.date AS date,
  other.slot,
  other.successful,
  calc.sum_successful,
  max((case when (rule.tree_si = dms.tree) then dms.numberResponses end))/successful AS percentage, 
  other.name AS ota_name,
  other.successful AS successful,
  max((case when (rule.tree_si = dms.tree) then dms.numberResponses end)) AS users_si
FROM  aca_ota_other other 
join aca_dms_rules rule on other.name = rule.ota_name
join aca_dms dms on dms.date = other.date and rule.tree_si = dms.tree
join (SELECT name, sum(successful) as sum_successful FROM aca_ota_other GROUP BY name) as calc on other.name = calc.name
GROUP BY 
  other.date,
  other.name,
  other.successful
ORDER BY other.date desc
```

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle did you try this?

Comment: But in Mysql is a error the subquery: You write in your MySQL Reference Manual :: 21.2 CREATE VIEW Syntax

Comment: what version of mysql?  did you checked the provided [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e991/13)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if i understood well, you need something like this:
I'm sorry, I've made some little changes in your query.

```
SELECT other.date date,
  other.slot,
  other.name ota_name,
  sum(successful) successful,
  dms.numberResponses users_si,
  SUM(successful)/dms.numberResponses AS percentage
FROM aca_ota_other other 
JOIN aca_dms_rules rule ON other.name=rule.ota_name
JOIN aca_dms dms ON dms.date=other.date AND rule.tree_si=dms.tree     
GROUP BY other.date,
  other.name
ORDER BY other.date DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e991/22

Comment: No because in this sql script the successful per day does not exist, and i need the successful per day in a column and in other the sum of successful with the same name and same date